# Como validar para que no salga NaN en un campo?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente función que se manda a llamar cuando entro a la pagina, pero en ese momento aun no tengo las variables llenas con valores, ya que se cargan hasta llenar unos combos y recargar la pagina.

La primera vez que entra, el campo `inputTotal`  muestra `NaN` me imagino porque no hay nada aun en la variable, y ya cuando lleno unos combos y se carga la pagina, ya se muestra en valor de la variable `total` en mi input

```html
function calcularTotal(){


var valor = parseInt($(#inputCalculo1).val());
var valor1 = parseInt($(#inputCalculo2).val());
var valor2 = parseInt($(#inputCalculo3).val());


var total = valor + valor1 + valor2;
document.getElementById("inputTotal").value=total;

}
```

Como puedo validar para que no salga eso en mi input la primera vez que entra a la pagina , sino que se muestre en blanco nada mas , y ya al llenar datos y cargar la pagina ya muestre el valor  de la variable

como le podría hacer?

Esta bien que haga el `parseInt` ?, los valores que tengo `inputCalculo1, inputCalculo2, y inputCalculo3` son valores numericos, y es que si no le pongo en parseInt al hacer la suma, no los suma, solo junta los números

Ojala me puedan apoyar, gracias

Answer (score 4):

Debes preguntar si el numero isNaN, en caso que lo sea lo cambias por **algo** y si no, lo dejas con su valor

```js
let total=Number.NaN;
isNaN(total)? total='algo':total;
console.log(total);
document.getElementById("inputTotal").innerHTML=total;
```

```html
<div id='inputTotal'></div>
```

Comment: si no quiero que salga un 0, sino que solo se muestre en blanco, se puede?

Comment: sustituye esto '0' por esto ' ' y debería mostrar el espacio en blanco @Root93

Answer (score 0):

Realizando una pequeña validación en la asignación de valores te aseguras de que la suma se realizará correctamente. Esto podemos llevarlo a cabo implementando una función en la que si el valor no es correcto se devuelva un 0.

```
function adaptar ( value ) {
  return !isNaN(value) ? value : 0;
}

function calcularTotal(){

  var valor = parseInt(adaptar($(#inputCalculo1).val()));
  var valor1 = parseInt(adaptar($(#inputCalculo2).val()));
  var valor2 = parseInt(adaptar$(#inputCalculo3).val()));
  var total = valor + valor1 + valor2;
  document.getElementById("inputTotal").value=total;

}
```